# PHP "multidimensional" array creation

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this code:

```
$mdArray = array(array());
$mdArray[0] = "1000";
$mdArray[0]["status"] = true;

echo $mdArray[0]["status"];
```

For some reason, this fails with a: Warning: Illegal string offset 'status'

There error occurs when I try to assign "true" to $mdArray[0]["status"] = "true";

If I already have an array within an array stored in the variable $mdArray, why is adding a "status" key to 0, failing?

Comment: You just cannot have a value on the level of [0] and then extend your array with a deeper level "status". You overwrite the value. You can dump your array with a `print_r($array);` statement to see this.

Comment: You can use 0 or 1 instead of true or false. Your problem will be solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because  $mdArray[0] is not an array , it should be an array like

```
$mdArray = array(array());
$mdArray[0] = array("1000");
$mdArray[0]["status"] = true;

echo $mdArray[0]["status"];
```

Comment: tell me if this help you or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

```
$mdArray = array();

$mdArray[0][] = "1000";
$mdArray[0]["status"] = true;

echo $mdArray[0]["status"];
```